# InnerException = Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

my code is

please give me solution...thank you

```
  bool b = false;
  string str=Server.MapPath("~/Files/"+filepath);


      //  Send the file to the browser
      Response.AddHeader("Content-type", filetype);
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

      Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + filepath));


      Response.Flush();
      //  HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
       Response.End();

      b = true;
```

Comment: What is the outer exception? We cannot answer if we don't know what the actual problem is. The inner exception is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you redirecting in your code ?

Comment: outer exception is ---
   Thread was being aborted.

Answer (score 3):

This notification means that the thread is currently executing code, and therefore cannot be used to evaluate the expression.

Use

```
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest
```

Instead of `Response.End();`

`Response.Flush` and `Response.End` does the same thing except `Response.End` stops execution of the page, and raises the `EndRequest` event.

Calls to the `End` methods throw a `ThreadAbortException` exception when the current response ends prematurely.

Comment: Thanks! We had the Unable to evaluate expression error and this answer saved our day!

Comment: @JPMarichal I am glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

So I ran into this same issue I was using an async trigger button

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_login" />
```

in an update panel. I switched to regular post back not the best but it worked.

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_login" />.
```

Since I was only redirecting on the page this was a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because Response.End gives a threadabortion error? see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx