# Aborting thread from timer event

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, threadabortexception, thread-abort

I have a `Timer` which has to cancel a `Thread` if it needs too much time.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer_timers = new System.Timers.Timer();
Thread thread = new Thread(startJob);
thread.Name = "VICTIM_THREAD";
```

when starting the `Thread` method I start the `Timer` and pass the current Thread to the event as parameter.

```
public void startJob()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    timer_timers.Elapsed += (sender, e) => T_Elapsed(sender, e, Thread.CurrentThread);
    timer_timers.Interval = 5000;

    // Start simulation process
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(700);
        Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " ALIVE: " + thread.IsAlive);
    }            
}
```

Timer event:

```
private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e, Thread currentThread)
{
    // EDIT: show the correct NAME! of the thread
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + currentThread.Name);

    System.Timers.Timer tim = sender as System.Timers.Timer;

    currentThread.Abort();  // <-- this line throws exception

    if (tim != null)
    {
        tim.Stop();
    }

}
```

But the `Abort` call throws me an Exception:

> 'Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack'

and the thread remains alive.
If I start the timer before the `startJob()` and pass the thread directly it works fine.

```
public void startThread()
{
    timer_timers.Elapsed += (sender, e) => T_Elapsed(sender, e, thread);
    timer_timers.Interval = 5000;

    timer_timers.Start();
    thread.Start();
}
public void startJob()
{
    // Start simulation process
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(700);
        Debug.WriteLine("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " ALIVE: " + thread.IsAlive);
    }            
}
```

Question: Why does the `Thread.CurrentThread` version not work? is it because I would also have to abort the timer thread? What am I missing here?

Answers I found to this exception like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131628/what-does-cannot-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-of-the-current-method-is) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219079/innerexception-unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or) are from  different context and don't really help me to understand exactly why.

EDIT: I know that this is the wrong way to abort or cancel a thread. The job it is supposed to do is to open a SerialPort. But once every ~200-th time the thread will just never return and I need to kill it nevermind the consequences. the simulation while loop is may be a bad example.

Comment: Do not ever call `Thread.Abort()` as it can leave the AppDomain in an undefined state. The only exception to this is if you are try to force your application to shut down and, in that case, you don't care about an undefined state.

Comment: In other words, the approach you are taking is the wrong way to terminate a thread and it is dangerous to do it this way.

Comment: Yeah, a better pattern is to use a CancellationToken to implement cooperative thread completion.  Can't answer why it's behaving in this manner, but it's known to have bad side effects. (edit) oh, you're not capturing the thread you think you are with `Thread.CurrentThread`.  Dark Falcon's answer is correct.

Comment: And if you DO want your application to shut down immediately, call `Environment.FailFast()`. In other words, there is no circumstance in which you should be calling `Thread.Abort()`.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Dispose` on the `SerialPort` instance from another thread to get it to unblock?

Comment: @spender no I have not. I just started to try this solution. Got this error and now I am trying to understand why this error appears.

Comment: thank you guys for the supportive comments, I read it a countless time. I still would like to understand the background workings behind this "phenomenon"

Comment: @spender good point, I will look into it. This is going probably to end up as the next question :)

Comment: @spender calling `Dispose` doesn't work unfortunately, good idea though. aborting the threads help neither. It remains stuck in `port.Open();` I found a couple of other posts. Old posts... interesting problem though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should not be using `Abort`. Even if you do, here is the issue with the way you're using it:

Timers don't run on your thread. They run on the thread pool thread. Hence `Thread.CurrentThread` used in your lambda is going to be that thread pool thread.

Here is what you should be doing if you want to abort the thread which is creating the timer: Capture the thread in a variable outside the lambda.

```
Thread myThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
timer_timers.Elapsed += (sender, e) => T_Elapsed(sender, e, myThread);
```

But you should be finding another way to terminate your thread more gracefully, or to rework your code to not need explicit threading.

Comment: the line: `Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);` in the `startJob` method and in the `Elapsed` both display the correct name = `VICTIM_THREAD`. does the thread pool thread get the same name?

Comment: No, it would not have the same name. I don't believe your test results due to the documentation, which says ["Provides a mechanism for executing a method on a thread pool thread at specified intervals."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) I think you've somehow tested incorrectly.

Comment: is it a theoretical non believe in my test results or did you compile and run my posted code?

Comment: It is based on the documentation (which I linked) and a LOT of experience (this is my daily job) with .NET. I don't have time to compile and run every single bit of code.

Comment: sounds reasonable, I am quite certain that I made somewhere a mistake, I just really would like to know where. :)

Comment: yo , my mistake, found it in the elapsed event it doesn't show the name! sorry for the turbulence

Comment: thank you beautiful solution it reminds me a little of the closure problem . So basically by capturing the thread it is "glued" to the new variable and won't be led to a wrong path via `Thread.CurrentThread` when the timer event is fired ?=! did I get it correctly ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is quite a common practice to capture some aspect of the state in the outer scope. One place you might also see this is in Javascript, where the value of `this` is different within a callback, and thus `this` must be captured in a variable in the outer scope in order to be used within the callback lambda.

Comment: sorry again for the agitated response. and thank you for the lesson (also in modesty) you really extended my understanding. I should spend more time reading the documentation and divert from explicit threading. I know that.

Answer (score 4):

Don't ever call `Thread.Abort`. Here's how to do it properly:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;

var t = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.Write(".");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}, token);

var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 5000;
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => tokenSource.Cancel();
timer.Enabled = true;
```

---

The reason that your code appears to work in the second case is that you are capturing the thread before the call to `T_Elapsed`. In the first case you are requesting the current thread only when the time `Elapsed` event is called (and at that point it isn't the calling thread, it's the callee).

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't really answer the question why it works in the second case but not in the first...

Comment: @Enigmativity, Also it will be more elegant if instead of Thread.Sleep(500); use token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(500)

Comment: @MongZhu - I've added the answer.

Comment: thank you, it really added to my understanding. especially in combination with Dark Falcon's answer.